# Creating Routes in File Geodatabase gives ERROR 000732?

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, python-addin, route, error-000732

UPDATE: I solved this issue by circumventing it - I moved to using the "in_memory" work space which also has improved the speed of my tool. The only change I had to make was to manually calculate the "FRM" field as zero that I created in the rd4Route shape.

I've got a function that I use to determine what side of the street an address is on. Previously I created routes and located features along those routes in a shapefile and dbf table, and I'd like to be able to have the same functionality in a file geodatabase instead. However, once I change the location to the geodatabase I created, the tool will no longer successfully create a route event layer. There are three lines where I changed the location to the gdb, I left the original (pre gdb) code under each one of those lines. I got the following error and warning:

```
ERROR 000732: Input Route Features: Dataset C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Local\ESRI\Desktop10.3\AssemblyCache\{7E9712E7-BFF6-420A-B125-F011DB68C687}\AddressingToolbarInstall.gdb\tempRoute does not exist or is not supported
WARNING 000725: Output Event Table: Dataset C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Local\ESRI\Desktop10.3\AssemblyCache\{7E9712E7-BFF6-420A-B125-F011DB68C687}\AddressingToolbarInstall.gdb\tempTable already exists.
Failed to execute (LocateFeaturesAlongRoutes).
```

I attempted to heed these messages, but to no avail - overwriteOutput is already set to True and I was not able to create the routes in my various configurations.

```
#must have proper stru and rd selected first
def parityChecker(rEven):
    #||Copy road to temporary & emptied feature class||
    rd4Route = os.path.join(installFolder, "AddressingToolbarInstall.gdb\\rdForRoute")
    #rd4Route = os.path.join(installFolder, "rdForRoute.shp")

    if arcpy.Exists(rd4Route) and int(arcpy.management.GetCount(rd4Route)[0]) > 0:
        arcpy.management.DeleteFeatures(rd4Route)
    arcpy.management.CopyFeatures(roads.roadChoice, rd4Route)
    arcpy.management.AddField(rd4Route, "FRM", "DOUBLE")
    arcpy.management.AddField(rd4Route, "SHPLEN", "DOUBLE")
    #calc "FRM" field = 0
    arcpy.management.CalculateField(rd4Route, "SHPLEN", "!shape.length@feet!", "PYTHON_9.3")

    #||Make route from rd and locate stru along the rd||
    route = os.path.join(installFolder, "AddressingToolbarInstall.gdb\\tempRoute")
    #route = os.path.join(installFolder, "tempRoute.shp")

    routeDbf = os.path.join(installFolder, "AddressingToolbarInstall.gdb\\tempTable")
    #routeDbf = os.path.join(installFolder, "tempTable.dbf")
    if arcpy.Exists(route) and int(arcpy.management.GetCount(route)[0]) > 0:
        arcpy.management.DeleteFeatures(route)

    arcpy.CreateRoutes_lr(rd4Route, "StreetName", route, "TWO_FIELDS","FRM","SHPLEN","LOWER_LEFT", "","","NO_IGNORE")
    arcpy.LocateFeaturesAlongRoutes_lr(structures.struChoice, route, "StreetName", "5280 FEET", routeDbf, "RID POINT MEAS")
```

Comment: I would change your if statement so that you're only looking to get the count of features once the existance has been confirmed. Your first if would be arcpy.Exists, then inside that another if to check the GetCount, then inside that, the DeleteFeatures.

Comment: Databases behave weird sometimes. Close arcgis, open, clean database and try again